# Merge first items of arrays within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays. I want to merge the first item from each array within the array. How could I go about that?

Here's my array:

```
var array = [["plums", "peaches", "pineapples"], ["carrots", "corn", "green beans"], ["chocolate", "ice cream"]];
```

I want the output to be:

```
var newArray = ["plums", "carrots", "chocolate"];
```

This is what I tried:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
  var array = [["plums", "peaches", "pineapples"], ["carrots", "corn", "green beans"], ["chocolate", "ice cream"]];

  var arrLength = array.length;
  var newArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
newArray = [].concat.apply([], array[i][0]);
  };
  console.log("new merged array:", newArray);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, in the console, I get this error:

> CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()`. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var array = [["plums", "peaches", "pineapples"], ["carrots", "corn", "green beans"], ["chocolate", "ice cream"]];
var newArray = array.map(x => x[0])
```

However, if you want to use a `for` loop to iterate the elements, you can do,

```
var newArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Since you want the first element,
    newArray.push(array[i][0])
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. So concise. Thanks!